# Grails: can't have an abstract method in a non-abstract class ERROR

Tags: java, validation, class, grails, abstract

Grails version: 2.3.4

Java version: 1.7.0_79

I was developing an uploader to AWS S3, from a demo, in a standalone app which was in the latest version of Grails. It is working and I've now been trying to implement it into my older Grails main app.

I'm coming into an error on server start with regards to this line of code:

```
import grails.validation.Validateable
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile

abstract class FeaturedImageCommand implements Validateable {
 MultipartFile featuredImageFile
 Long id
 Long eventId
 Integer version

static constraints = {
    id nullable: false
    version nullable: false
    eventId nullable:false

    featuredImageFile  validator: { val, obj ->
        if ( val == null ) {
            return false
        }
        if ( val.empty ) {
            return false
        }

        ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png'].any { extension -> // <1>
             val.originalFilename?.toLowerCase()?.endsWith(extension)
        }
    }
}
```

}

The error reads:

Can't have an abstract method in a non-anstract class. The class 'FeaturedImageCommand' must be declared abstract or the method 'java.lang.Class.annotationType()' must be implemented.

I'm assuming my java and grails versions are causing this, but I'm really hoping there is a way around this without updating them?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you don't understand !?  `Can't have an abstract method in a non-anstract class.`

Comment: I don't understand how this solution is working in my project of the more recent versions compared to the older

Answer (score 0):

Well `Validateable` is an annotation type, and the `annotationType()` method comes from the `Annotation` interface, which all `@interface` types implicitly inherit.

(Your code is ... odd.  Why would you want to "implement" an annotation as a class?  My understanding is that you won't be able to use a class defined as subclass of an `@interface` as an annotation ...)

- If you are trying to declare annotations with a type hierarchy, that is not permitted by the Java syntax.  (The JLS says this explicitly.)
- If you (really) want a class that `implements` an `@interface` then you will need to implement that method.  (And I have no idea how you got away with not doing this previously.  `Validateable` is an `@interface` in all versions that I can see on the Grepcode site.)

Comment: Hey, thank you for that info. Check out my updated post explaining the use of validator...I should have included it to begin with.

Comment: Hmmm ... I get it.  This is Grails code not Java code.  Well, I imagine that the problem is on the Grails side.  However, this still doesn't explain why that code is implementing an @interface?

Comment: And if you wrote that in Java, you *would* need to (ultimately) implement that method if a class implemented an @interface.  So I'm thinking that it is a bug in the Groovy compiler to not report an error, and what you have found is that the compiler bug has been fixed.  And what you should be doing is fixing that (apparent) bug in your code, not looking for a Groovy / Grails implementation that allows it.